# Get last unbroken sequence of a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of time series with gaps stored as `pd.Series`. How can I efficiently get the "last unbroken" sequence of data points (i.e. not containing any `NaN` values)?

My original series might be something like:

```
2014-12-01    500
2015-02-01    700
2015-03-01    700
dtype: float64
```

I can easily transform this series into a regular one using `pd.Series.asfreq`, e.g. `series.asfreq('MS')` gives:

```
2014-12-01    500
2015-01-01    NaN
2015-02-01    700
2015-03-01    700
dtype: float64
```

In this case, I would like to get the series from 2015-02-01 and onwards:

```
2015-02-01    700
2015-03-01    700
dtype: float64
```

Here's what I come up with, but it seems ugly:

```
# Let i be the first position we're getting, default to entire series
i = 0

# Find any NaN values in the Series
nan_index = series[series.isnull()].index
if len(nan_index):
    # Find the position of the last null value in the original
    # series (+ 1 to skip it)
    i = series.index.get_loc(nan_index[-1]) + 1

series.iloc[i:]
```

Comment: I just posted by response and then noticed it is basically what you have above.  I think it is fine, except I would add `.tolist()` at the end of your `nan_index` assignment and then use `s.iloc[s.index.get_loc(nan_idx[-1]) + 1:] if nan_idx else s`.

Comment: That's neater, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possible trick is to look for indices that are not null, and also where the cumsum of null entries matches to total sum of null entries. Then this can be done with fancy indexing.

This is just the sort of 'clever trick' that Dijkstra probably would tell us all to avoid, since it's not that readable and could be subtly broken (for example, this assumes the index is sorted as you desire ahead of time). I don't think there's anything wrong with a more verbose, but more straightforward solution like directly computing the index of the final Null, unless you can profile it and know for sure that this is a major performance issue.

```
In [35]: s
Out[35]: 
2014-12-01    500
2015-02-01    700
2015-03-01    700
dtype: int64

In [36]: s_ms = s.asfreq('MS')

In [37]: s_ms_null = s_ms.isnull()

In [38]: s[~s_ms_null & (s_ms_null.cumsum() == s_ms_null.sum())]
Out[38]: 
2015-02-01    700
2015-03-01    700
dtype: int64
```